# Object reference not set to an instance of an object execep occur while add the value for list in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, automatic-properties

Object reference not set to an instance of an object Exception thrown..(Null referenceException was  unhandled by user code)

Model:

```
public class AboutMod
{
    private List<int> divWidthList = new List<int>();
    public List<int> DivWidthList { get; set; }
}
```

Control page:

```
 public ActionResult About()
        {
            AboutMod Obj = new AboutMod();//model class name 
            for (int i = 20; i <= 100; i += 20)
            {
                Obj.DivWidthList.Add(10);//Run time Exception occurs here 
            }
                return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialise `Obj.DivWidthList` first before attempting to use it:

```
    AboutMod Obj = new AboutMod();//model class name 

    Obj.DivWidthList = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 20; i <= 100; i += 20)
    {            
        Obj.DivWidthList.Add(10);//Run time Exception occurs here 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no relation between your private field `divWidthList` and the public property `DivWidthList`. The public property is never initialized. You could initialize it for example in the constructor of the class:

```
public class AboutMod
{
    public AboutMod
    {
        DivWidthList = new List<int>();
    }
    public List<int> DivWidthList { get; set; }
}
```

or don't use an auto property:

```
public class AboutMod
{
    private List<int> divWidthList = new List<int>();
    public List<int> DivWidthList 
    {
        get
        {
            return divWidthList;
        }
        set
        {
            divWidthList = value;
        }
    }
}
```